# Вызов скрипта при сохранении

Tags: php, netbeans, javascript

Здравствуйте, необходимость в PHP проекте при сохранении вызывать скрипт. Например, `file.sh`, чтобы собрать все `js` и `css` файлы и откомпилить их с помощью `yui-compressor`. А то приходится в ручную каждый раз из терминала это делать.

Подскажите как в `NetBeans` это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю Вас поможет это 
1) http://webartisan.se/yui-compressor-netbeans/ - тут можно использовать `run.bat` вместо `run.sh` в `Windows`

2) http://nnbs.blogspot.com/2008/11/updated-minified-javascript-and-css.html
3) https://arkblog.wordpress.com/2008/12/02/minify-javascript-and-css-files-in-ide-netbeans-and-eclipse/

или использование ANT

4) http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheAnt/article.html